# How do we understand these words of Jesus from John 6:57 “…I live because of the Father…”?

Tags: john, jesus

> John 6:57: As the living Father sent Me, and I live because of the Father, so he who eats Me, he also will live because of Me.

What does he mean by **live**?

Comment: If God would not have uttered His Word, then the Word would not have come into existence (John 1 and Genesis 1).

Comment: that seems very easy to misunderstand - can you be more specific, 'flesh out' - perhaps in an answer?

Comment: The Father fathers His Son; without a Father, there is not Son.

Answer (score 0):

**How do we understand these words of Jesus from John 6:57 “…I live because of the Father…”?**

John 6:56-57 (NASB)

> 56 He who eats My flesh and drinks My blood abides in Me, and I in
> him. 57 As the living Father sent Me, and I live because of the
> Father, so he who eats Me, he also will live because of Me.

The very fact that Jesus is called the “Son of God” reveals that he was produced by the Father and is, therefore, his firstborn and only-begotten Son.  Jesus’ own statements. point to God as the Source of his life, saying, “I live because of the Father.” According to the context, this meant that his life resulted from or was caused by his Father.

Answer (score -2):

He really means what he says - except for the Father, Jesus would still be in the grave.

There are several ways in which Jesus received life from the Father. Before we get to John 6:57, there are other important verses that show Jesus' total dependency on the Father - all these aspects are included in John 6:57.

1. Even though he never sinned and was legally set apart from the death penalty of sinners, he could not and did not raise himself from death after his crucifixion.

> Rom 6:4 Christ was raised from the dead through the glory of the Father (also Gal 1:1)

> John 10:18 No one takes it from me, but I lay it down of my own accord. I have authority to lay it down and authority to take it up again

This **authority** he received from his Father. We must remember, Jesus is without the corruption of sin and the deep impact it has on a person's soul, heart, mind  and spirit. He is 'at one' with the Father in ways we can barely even pray about. He has spent the preceding verses telling them about him being the door, the shepherd, and in other conversations, the judge, the sacrificial lamb, and many other roles - he says he has the authority to be and do all these things - even to dying and living again. The Father is behind every step and their confidence should be strengthened in this truth.

2. Jesus prayed to the Father to save him from eternal death - which would have been the result if he had sinned just once while in the flesh. This is not about his death on the cross.

> Heb 5:7 During the days of Jesus’ earthly life, He offered up prayers and petitions with loud cries and tears to the One who could save Him from death

3. Jesus was mortal in the flesh. When the Father raised him he became immortal with the new spirit life.

> For Christ also died for sins once for all, the just for the unjust, so that He might bring us to God, having been put to death in the flesh, but made alive in the spirit; 1 Pet 3:18

> Rom 6:9 Christ, having been raised from the dead, is never to die again; death no longer is master over Him

4. When he was born of Mary, it was because of the Father through His spirit Luke 1:35
5. He NOW has life in himself - just as the Father always did. This speaks of his immortal life that he was raised into and can also impart to others.

> John 5:26 For as the Father has life in Himself, so also He has granted the Son to have life in Himself.

And so in John 6:57, Jesus explains how **we can 'live'** because of what Jesus accomplished, just as **how he now lives** because of the Father, through what he accomplished in his life up to the final victory on the cross. Our eternal life will be as his is - His life in the Father, our life in him!

Comment: This does terrible violence to the language of the original: #5 is present not future; #4 is not germane; #3 is Jesus gift to us not the Father's gift to Jesus! #2 is misapplied - no request for eternal life in there!